# Audio glitches every few seconds with VLC and the ALC1220 codec

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, vlc

VLC is producing regular audio glitches (every 3 seconds) for me in 17.10 with my new X299 system that has a Realtek ALC1220 audio codec.  The glitches seem to be specific to VLC and don't occur with aplay or mplayer.  After doing a little digging, it looks like VLC's complex audio timing system is seeing a timing drift in the info returned from the codec and inserting silences to compensate for it (you can see this under VLC's messages at debug level 1).

I haven't seen any other posts on this issue and I'm curious if anyone else with an ALC1220 codec is seeing a problem with VLC (or any other codec).  If so, let me know what you're seeing and if you've found a work-around for it.

Comment: All audio issues aside - that's awesome that you've built a x299 system and installed Ubuntu!

Comment: ALC1220 is an audio device (hardware) not software coder-decoder.
you have identified problem - vlc complex settings.
and workaround - use another player than vlc

Comment: ASRock X299 Taichi with a Realtek ALC1220. Same exact VLC audio glitch every 3 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation it turns out that the issue isn't with the audio chip, it's with my system RTC clock having about a 4% drift. VLC sees the drift and inserts silences in order to compensate for the delay.

To test for this, turn off the ntp server (`sudo systemctl stop systemd-timesyncd`) and use `date` to compare the time to an accurate external clock over a period of time. On my system I'm loosing about 12 seconds over a period of 5 minutes.

To fix the issue:

- You many want to turn off NTP first but I'm not certain this is
  required
- Install adjtimex: `sudo apt install adjtimex`
- Analyze the drift: `sudo adjtimexconfig`

  - This will automatically analyze the drift and put adjustment parameters in `/etc/default/adjtimex`
  - The parameters are immediately loaded into the system and will be reloaded on boot
- Check that the update was made: `adjtimex -p`
- redo the `date` to external clock test.

  - You should now see no drift.
- Turn back on NTP if you turned it off.

Comment: Fix works perfectly for 17.10.1

Comment: BTW,  for me this is due to a kernel bug having to do with the calibration of the TSC timer on SkylakeX.  That bug is now fixed in the latest 4.15 kernel release.

Answer (score 0):

biyouac0 Thanks for that answer looks like this is my problem. I gain ~40 seconds over 5 minutes. Unfortunately being very new to Linux (about 1 month) I don't understand what the fix is and what it accomplishes. Could you take a few minutes to explain. Also did this glitch also affect your video, mine has a zigzag line that comes and goes, especially when the screen is bright. I seems to be a refresh rate issue but this time drift would seem to fit. Linux Mint Mate 19.1   Thanks in advance

HP Notebook (W7B87UA#ABL)64 bits
product: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3710  @ 1.60GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0

```
      size: 4GiB
```

*-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series

Comment: Linux has an internal real-time-clock that keeps time by counting some type of timing ticks from the CPU.  On boot-up it does a calibration step to figure out how long each tick is.  Unfortunately it doesn't always get the timing correct, leading to a drift in the system clock.  The `adjtimex` utility provides a high level calibration / compensation to eliminate the drift.  The Linux RTC is a bit complicated and I can't explain it all, but you can google for info on it.  In regards to the video, I don't see how the RTC would impact this.  That sounds like a separate issue.

Comment: FYI.. Linux relies on the CPU's TSC to update its clock (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter).  Unfortunately the specifics of this vary from CPU to CPU.  In the case of my SkylakeX, the clocks-per-second value was simply coded incorrectly in the kernel.  That has since been fixed.  `adjtimex` is a simple utility you can use to compensate for drift caused when the kernel doesn't get the calibration correct.